# OpenGL VBO Normals/Lighting Issue

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

I can not get normals to render properly with a VBO. Below is the code I am using, with vertices being an array holding the vertices, and normals being an array holding the normals:

```
//Create the buffers and such
GLuint VBOID;
glGenBuffersARB(1, &VBOID);
glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, VBOID);
glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, sizeof(vertices) + sizeof(normals), 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
glBufferSubDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices);
glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);

///Start loop
cout << "Starting" << endl;
while( window.isOpen() ) {
    sf::Event event;
    while( window.pollEvent( event ) ) {
        if( event.type == sf::Event::Closed )
            window.close();
    }
    fps = FPS.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
    fps = 1 / fps;
    FPS.restart();
    if(ShowFPS.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() > 1)
    {
        cout << "FPS: " << fps << "\t FrameTime: " << 1000 / fps << endl;
        ShowFPS.restart();
    }

    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(50.0, 1.0, 1.0, 5000);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);

    //VBO
    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, VBOID);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(25 * TurnTimer.getElapsedTime().asSeconds(), 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(15 * TurnTimer.getElapsedTime().asSeconds(), 1, 0, 0);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, (void*)sizeof(vertices));
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NumOfF*3);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);

    window.display();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
glBufferSubDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices);
```

OK, so where's the part where you do this for your *normals*?

Also, please stop using the ARB extension functions. It's been core OpenGL functionality for almost a decade now; drop the ARB suffix already.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that fixed it. 

The reason I was using ARB extensions was because I was following the NeHe tutorials, which are a bit out-of-date.

Comment: @LucasS *"which are a bit out-of-date"* - That's exactly why you should **not** follow them. *NeHe* has been a good resource back in time, but even the best (not to imply they were) and most widely known tutorials should be given the chance to retire with dignity.